# MessageReceiver.RegisterMessageHandler throws exceptions continuously if network is down

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus

I have successfully implemented a connection to ServiceBus with `MessageReceiver` using `RegisterMessageHandler` that starts a pump (from this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/SendersReceiversWithTopics/Program.cs)) and all seems to work just fine.

But in case of exception like e.g. when I turn off network connection the pump throws exceptions continuously to the ExceptionHandler. Every second or even faster. I am wondering if this is supposed default behavior and more importantly if it's possible to change, so that e.g. connection retries can happen every 1 minute. Or am I supposed to do `Thread.Sleep` or something to achieve that?

```
receiver.RegisterMessageHandler(
    async (message, cancellationToken1) => await HandleMessage(receiver, message),
    new MessageHandlerOptions(HandleException)
    {
        AutoComplete = false, 
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 1
    });
```

P.S. This is how I solved it now, but not sure if it's a proper way:

```
private Task HandleException(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    _logger.Error(...);
     return Task.Delay(60000);
}
```

P.S Here is the `RetryPolicy.Default` dump:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus has a default retry policy (`RetryPolicy.Default`), but given the transport is trying to receive messages and the broker is not available, will raise exceptions.

`ExceptionReceivedContext` provides a context, `ExceptionReceivedContext` which has an action that has failed, and the original exception. You can evaluate the [action](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/ExceptionReceivedEventArgsAction.cs) and decide what needs to be done. You could also check if the exception is transient or not. For transient errors, based on the action, you could just wait for the message to be retried again later (`Receive` action). In other cases you could either log an error or take a more specific action.

Comment: I have added a dump of the `RetryPolicy.Default` and it does not really seems that it is used. E.g. it says `MaxRetryCount = 5`, but it is really infinite and happens every second rather that with Exponential backoff. I see that `MessageReciever` has the same policy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the "RetryExponential" on your "SubscriptionClient" like this:

```
var receiver = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SubscriptionClient(_serviceBusConnString, _topic, _subscription, this._receiveMode, new RetryExponential(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), _retryPolicyMaximumRetryCount));
```

This is the parameters descriptions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.retryexponential?view=azure-dotnet

Here other post about what the properties means:

[ServiceBus RetryExponential Property Meanings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499661/servicebus-retryexponential-property-meanings)